# Centring a div horizontally inside another div with absolute position state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to centre a div horizontally inside another div. The div that I am trying to centre is a scroll-down button that uses jQuery and has a custom icon font made by me and default width/height. I want to centre this div inside my main div and keep the original size as I want to keep using it as a button. For example:
[image: description]
I want to make something like the white arrow that is pointing down in the centre but without messing with my width.
 This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="intro-tab"> <!-- First/Intro Tab -->
    <div id="introtab-godownbtn">Q</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#intro-tab {
    width: auto; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    background-color: red; 
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
}

#introtab-godownbtn {
    font-family: iconFont; 
    font-size: 50px; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 25px; 
    width: 60px; 
    height: 30px; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: 30px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#introtab-godownbtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#introtab-godownbtn').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ 
        scrollTop: (screen.height - 90) 
    }, 600);
    return false; 
});
```

I have tried many ways to centre the button `introtab-godownbtn` but it doesn't work or it just messes up my buttons size and clicking location. Any solution to my problem?

Comment: Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/eT7U9/314/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to horizontally center an HTML element. Generally, one would use the `margin: 0 auto;` approach where a fixed width is set on the element it's being applied to. Here's an example of such: http://jsfiddle.net/5XTq2/

Can you provide a mockup/screenshot of the layout you're trying to achieve, if this answer doesn't help? I can happily update the answer to accommodate your need.

EDIT:
As per your Spotify example, if you inspect the page and select the down arrow, it will have the follow styles.

```
.scroller-arrow {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(../i/_global/arrow-big.png);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I added a photo explaining that

Comment: @AxerFli In that case, my example works perfectly. I looked at Spotify's CSS and they are also using the `margin: 0 auto;` technique that I used.

Answer (score 0):

To get the inner absolutely positioned div to be horizontally and vertically centered:

- http://jsfiddle.net/7P4n5/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

HTML:

```
<div id="intro-tab">
    <div id="introtab-godownbtn">Q</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; }
#intro-tab {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000;
}
#introtab-godownbtn {
    background-color: #FFF;    
    font-family: iconFont;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 60px;

    /* this does the centering */
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#introtab-godownbtn:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```